# Partition help for MacBook Pro trying to install windows

Tags: disk-utility, bootcamp, partition

I tried installing Windows 10 on my MacBook Pro (2016). The partition created by Bootcamp is there but the operation keeps failing and I can’t delete the partition to start again. The screenshots below are from failed attempts and Disk Utility. My computer knowledge is limited.

[image: Screenshot of the Boot Camp Assistant window preparing for the installation of Windows 10]

[image: Screenshot of Boot Camp giving an error of 'Your disk could not be partitioned']

[image: Screenshot of Disk Utility window showing the partitions on the SSD]

[image: Screenshot of Terminal showing the output of the command diskutil list]

[image: Screenshot of Disk Utility window showing the information for a disk image]

```
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 limits
Resize limits for APFS Physical Store partition disk0s2:
  Current Physical Store partition size on map: 500.1 GB (500068036608 Bytes)
  Minimum (constrained by file/snapshot usage): 428.2 GB (428157907763 Bytes)
  Recommended minimum (if used with macOS): 438.9 GB (438895326003 Bytes)
  Maximum (constrained by partition map space): 500.1 GB (500068036608 Bytes)
```

Comment: For what you have posted, there does not appear to be any problems with the drive partitioning. Have you tried running First Aid as suggested by the posted error message? You can do this using the Disk Utility or `diskutil` command. You could post to your question any error you may find. However, if the errors can not be automatically repaired, you probably will have to erase and reinstall macOS.

Comment: Hi yes I have run first aid in both recovery and normal mode- no issues.

Comment: What does `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 limits` show?

Comment: just trying to work out how to add a screenshot to comments!

Comment: diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 limits
Resize limits for APFS Physical Store partition disk0s2:
  Current Physical Store partition size on map:   500.1 GB (500068036608 Bytes)
  Minimum (constrained by file/snapshot usage):   428.2 GB (428157907763 Bytes)
  Recommended minimum (if used with macOS):       438.9 GB (438895326003 Bytes)
  Maximum (constrained by partition map space):   500.1 GB (500068036608 Bytes)

Comment: You could have edited your question and added the screenshot. Or, added the text.

Comment: Try creating the partition for Windows by entering the following command. `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 458G exfat BOOTCAMP 0` Post the output to your question.

Comment: Started APFS operation
Aligning shrink delta to 42,068,037,632 bytes and targeting a new physical store size of 457,999,998,976 bytes
Determined the minimum size for the targeted physical store of this APFS Container to be 407,854,120,960 bytes
Resizing APFS Container designated by APFS Container Reference disk1
The specific APFS Physical Store being resized is disk0s2
Verifying storage system
Using live mode

Comment: Performing fsck_apfs -n -x -l /dev/disk0s2
Checking the container superblock
Checking the EFI jumpstart record
Checking the space manager
Checking the space manager free queue trees
Checking the object map
Checking the encryption key structures
Checking volume /dev/rdisk1s1
Checking the APFS volume superblock
Checking the object map
Checking the snapshot metadata tree
Checking the snapshot metadata
Checking the document ID tree
Checking the fsroot tree

Comment: error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 106267, file-id 8679613075 but no inode references this doc-id
error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 106282, file-id 8679613274 but no inode references this doc-id
error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 106327, file-id 8679613874 but no inode references this doc-id
error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 106331, file-id 8679613890 but no inode references this doc-id
error: doc-id tree: record exists for doc-id 106350, file-id 8679614330 but no inode references this doc-id

Comment: Storage system check exit code is 8
Error: -69716: Storage system verify or repair failed
Andrews-MacBook-Pro:~ Andrew$ Started APFS operation
-bash: Started: command not found
Andrews-MacBook-Pro:~ Andrew$ Aligning shrink delta to 42,068,037,632 bytes and targeting a new physical store size of 457,999,998,976 bytes
-bash: Aligning: command not found
Andrews-MacBook-Pro:~ Andrew$ Determined the minimum size for the targeted physical store of this APFS Container to be 407,854,120,960 bytes
-bash: Determined: command not found

Comment: theres quite a long string from here

Comment: this is the last part of it

Comment: 7, file-id 8680162598 but no inode references this doc-id
-bash: error:: command not found
Andrews-MacBook-Pro:~ Andrew$ Storage system check exit code is 8
-bash: Storage: command not found
Andrews-MacBook-Pro:~ Andrew$ Error: -69716: Storage system verify or repair failed
-bash: Error:: command not found
Andrews-MacBook-Pro:~ Andrew$

Comment: What can I say. I asked if you ran first aid and you replied yes. Evidently, you must have run first aid on the entire drive instead of the partition holding the APFS container. I say this because the `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 458G exfat BOOTCAMP 0` command first does a verify on the APFS container. Your posted output shows a failure. With such a failure, the partitions needed to install Windows will never be created.

Comment: ok, I do appreciate your time and help with this, afraid my computer knowledge is quite limited, to clarify, I need to run first aid on just the partition?

Comment: Yes. If the repair fails, then you may need to erase the APFS container.

Comment: Thank you David, ran repair, recommended repair in recovery mode…all done. Thanks again for your time.